# Скачать большой файл FastAPI

Tags: python, файлы, fastapi

Я написал функцию, которая загружает файл. Файл скачивается в папку, однако процесс установки не виден в браузере, видно только когда файл скачался. Мой код:

```
@router.get("/files/install_mp4", status_code=200)
async def get_mp4():
    res = "video.mp4"
    CHUNK_SIZE = 1024*1024

    async def iterfile():
        async with aiofiles.open(res, mode="rb") as f:
            while chunk := await f.read(CHUNK_SIZE):
                yield chunk
    headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="video.mp4"'}
    return StreamingResponse(iterfile(), media_type="video/mp4", headers=headers)
```

Я хочу видеть процесс загрузки файла, как здесь[image], однако я получаю только так[image]

Также и в документации swagger, при get-запросе мне приходит download file, но кнопка неактивна около 10 секунд, когда становится активна, то файл скачивается сразу (300 МБ)

После отправки запроса, если я обновлю страницу, то загрузка прервется, как этого избежать?

Я хочу, чтобы при скачивании файла был виден весь процесс скачивания файла, как это обычно происходит.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить хедер content-length, возможно тогда браузер вас поймет

Comment: @Darth, пробовал, не помогает

Comment: Попробуйте FileResponse использовать просто с путем, в [документации](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#fileresponse) написано, что он асинхронно стримит файл ("Asynchronously streams a file as the response."), т.е. теоретически внутри работает так же как вы вручную хотите реализовать. P.S. вот исходник FileResponse, кстати, там видно что асинхронно чанками файл отправляется: https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/master/starlette/responses.py#L267

Comment: @insolor, пробовал с FileReponse вот так: 
headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="video.mp4"',
               'Content-Length': str(total_size)}
    # return StreamingResponse(iterfile(), media_type="video/mp4", headers=headers)
    return FileResponse(
        path=res, media_type="video/mp4",
        filename="video.mp4",
        headers=headers
    )
Поведение такое же, кнопка download неактивна в течении 10 секунд, а потом файл скачивается целиком и падает в загрузки, хотелось бы весь процесс видеть

Comment: Пробовали просто пример из документации без дополнительных headers?

Comment: @insolor, дополнительный headers такие прописывал
headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="video.mp4"', 'Content-Length': str(total_size)}

Comment: Еще раз: вообще без них пробовали? FileResponse сам проставляет тот же Content-Length и другие дополнительные хэдеры

Comment: @insolor, без них тоже пробовал, в ответ приходи Error: OK, но файл также скачивается , как и раньше

Comment: То есть когда я делаю запрос, файл начинает скачиваться, если я обновлю страницу, то загрузка прервется

Comment: @insolor, а если обновить страницу, то файл должен продолжать скачиваться? У меня этот процесс прерывается

Comment: Пробовали другой браузер? Я пока не могу потестировать ваш код. Не помню точно как скачивание работает, но возможно от браузера зависит.

Comment: Да, пробовал в 4 разных браузерах, везде одинаково работает